# FlyWeight Design Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I was Going through an example of flyweight Pattern i found online.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.HashMap;

// A common interface for all players
interface Player
{
    public void assignWeapon(String weapon);
    public void mission();
}

// Terrorist must have weapon and mission
class Terrorist implements Player
{
    // Intrinsic Attribute
    private final String TASK;

    // Extrinsic Attribute
    private String weapon;

    public Terrorist()
    {
        TASK = "PLANT A BOMB";
    }
    public void assignWeapon(String weapon)
    {
        // Assign a weapon
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }
    public void mission()
    {
        //Work on the Mission
        System.out.println("Terrorist with weapon "
                        + weapon + "|" + " Task is " + TASK);
    }
}

// CounterTerrorist must have weapon and mission
class CounterTerrorist implements Player
{
    // Intrinsic Attribute
    private final String TASK;

    // Extrinsic Attribute
    private String weapon;

    public CounterTerrorist()
    {
        TASK = "DIFFUSE BOMB";
    }
    public void assignWeapon(String weapon)
    {
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }
    public void mission()
    {
        System.out.println("Counter Terrorist with weapon "
                        + weapon + "|" + " Task is " + TASK);
    }
}

// Claass used to get a playeer using HashMap (Returns
// an existing player if a player of given type exists.
// Else creates a new player and returns it.
class PlayerFactory
{
    /* HashMap stores the reference to the object
    of Terrorist(TS) or CounterTerrorist(CT). */
    private static HashMap <String, Player> hm =
                        new HashMap<String, Player>();

    // Method to get a player
    public static Player getPlayer(String type)
    {
        Player p = null;

        /* If an object for TS or CT has already been
        created simply return its reference */
        if (hm.containsKey(type))
                p = hm.get(type);
        else
        {
            /* create an object of TS/CT */
            switch(type)
            {
            case "Terrorist":
                System.out.println("Terrorist Created");
                p = new Terrorist();
                break;
            case "CounterTerrorist":
                System.out.println("Counter Terrorist Created");
                p = new CounterTerrorist();
                break;
            default :
                System.out.println("Unreachable code!");
            }

            // Once created insert it into the HashMap
            hm.put(type, p);
        }
        return p;
    }
}

// Driver class
public class CounterStrike
{
    // All player types and weopons (used by getRandPlayerType()
    // and getRandWeapon()
    private static String[] playerType =
                    {"Terrorist", "CounterTerrorist"};
    private static String[] weapons =
    {"AK-47", "Maverick", "Gut Knife", "Desert Eagle"};


    // Driver code
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        /* Assume that we have a total of 10 players
        in the game. */
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            /* getPlayer() is called simply using the class
            name since the method is a static one */
            Player p = PlayerFactory.getPlayer(getRandPlayerType());

            /* Assign a weapon chosen randomly uniformly
            from the weapon array */
            p.assignWeapon(getRandWeapon());

            // Send this player on a mission
            p.mission();
        }
    }

    // Utility methods to get a random player type and
    // weapon
    public static String getRandPlayerType()
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        // Will return an integer between [0,2)
        int randInt = r.nextInt(playerType.length);

        // return the player stored at index 'randInt'
        return playerType[randInt];
    }
    public static String getRandWeapon()
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        // Will return an integer between [0,5)
        int randInt = r.nextInt(weapons.length);

        // Return the weapon stored at index 'randInt'
        return weapons[randInt];
    }
}
```

**Implementation** : This implement the creation of Terrorists and Counter Terrorists In the game of Counter Strike. So we have 2 classes one for Terrorist(T) and other for Counter Terrorist(CT). Whenever a player asks for a weapon we assign him the asked weapon. In the mission, terrorist’s task is to plant a bomb while the counter terrorists have to diffuse the bomb.

I believe This example is wrong.In this code Object remains the same, we are only changing the weapon, if a new Player enters the game, everyone weapon's will changed. Am i understanding this right?.
Can anyone Provide me a good example of Fly Weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right your example is wrong. You only have 2 players in the hashmap (CT et Tero). Using an hashmap to store 2 object that are mandatory to play is pretty boilerplate.

And since you have only two play and you are changing their attribut you are in fact changing all player config :)

I have [modified a litle the example](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/alCjGqz4Md) to show that is wrong. I Simply store the player in an array and then reprint it.

```
     System.out.println("reuse --------------------------");
    for(Player p : players){
        p.mission();
    }
```

this give me the flowwing output :

```
    Terrorist Created
Terrorist with weapon Maverick| Task is PLANT A BOMB
Counter Terrorist Created
Counter Terrorist with weapon AK-47| Task is DIFFUSE BOMB
Terrorist with weapon AK-47| Task is PLANT A BOMB
Terrorist with weapon Maverick| Task is PLANT A BOMB
Terrorist with weapon Gut Knife| Task is PLANT A BOMB
Counter Terrorist with weapon Desert Eagle| Task is DIFFUSE BOMB
Terrorist with weapon Gut Knife| Task is PLANT A BOMB
Counter Terrorist with weapon Gut Knife| Task is DIFFUSE BOMB
Terrorist with weapon Maverick| Task is PLANT A BOMB
Terrorist with weapon Maverick| Task is PLANT A BOMB
reuse --------------------------
Terrorist with weapon Maverick| Task is PLANT A BOMB
Counter Terrorist with weapon Gut Knife| Task is DIFFUSE BOMB
Terrorist with weapon Maverick| Task is PLANT A BOMB
Terrorist with weapon Maverick| Task is PLANT A BOMB
Terrorist with weapon Maverick| Task is PLANT A BOMB
Counter Terrorist with weapon Gut Knife| Task is DIFFUSE BOMB
Terrorist with weapon Maverick| Task is PLANT A BOMB
Counter Terrorist with weapon Gut Knife| Task is DIFFUSE BOMB
Terrorist with weapon Maverick| Task is PLANT A BOMB
Terrorist with weapon Maverick| Task is PLANT A BOMB
```

You clearly see that every team as the same weapon (the last chosen).

If you want good example follow references of you article ;) :) :) like [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern#Example_in_Java)

The principale is to reuse a config is that is already created.